# Sometimes retrieving only name as string, without components of place

Tags: google-places-api

Retrieved object (restricted by AU, type is address):

[image]

Comment: After 5-10 minutes same request return normal object with components and other properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example by Google own:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
I see same issue with this address:
1757 Princes Highway, Heywood, Victoria, Australia

So need to create bug in their system.

UPD: created bug https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10381&thanks=10381&ts=1472557820

Thanks for time spent!